# Does it make sense theoretically to lag my dependent variable?

Tags: regression, least-squares, autocorrelation, lags, durbin-watson-test

I am currently doing a research on the correlation between the duration of conflicts and religious organisations. For this, I am doing a multiple linear regression, with my dependent variable being the duration of conflicts in years (interval-ratio, assuming a value of y>0), and my independent variable is religion in the public discourse (dichotomous). After running the regression, I noticed that my Durbin-Watson value was very low, so I reorganised cases in chronological order, which improved it but still did not make it acceptable. Then I tried lagging the dependent variable, which worked and raised my Durbin-Watson value to 1.510.

My question is, does lagging my dependent variable make sense theoretically? From what I have read and been taught in my courses this is better suited for other cases, where including cases registered as time-series results in autocorrelation. However, does it make sense when looking at the duration of conflicts in years?

(The dataset I am using registers conflicts on a year-basis, so each case corresponds to one particular year, and thus prolonged conflicts are divided in multiple cases. However, I do not think that the problem which may derive from this aspect really apply to my regression.)

The model equation without the lagged dependent variable is:
duration_conlfict = -4.323 + 6.87*religion_in_public + 0.319*regime_type + 1.769*GDP

With the lagged dependent variable:
duration_conlfict = 0.264 + 0.244*religion_in_public + 0.000*regime_type + 0.117*GDP + 0.977*LAG_duration

However when I tried doing all these operations again from the initial dataset, my results changed, especially in regards to the Durbin-Watson score (which is 1.919 with the LAG_duration), and the significance of my predictors (which has decreased significantly compared to the previous attempts).

Comment: Can you write your model equation in these two cases?

Comment: One of the ways to make autocorrelation intuitive is to ask whether the dependent variable 'remembers' its past values. For example, the prevalence of an infectious disease like HIV/AIDS in year $t$ for sure comes from the prevalence of HIV/AIDS in the previous year $t-1$ (because (a) new cases come from existing cases, and (b) old cases may have survived to the current year). I do not know much about your subject area, but do *you* expect that your dependent variable at time $t$ is completely unrelated to your dependent variable at time(s) $t-j$? If not, be comfortable with lagged $y$!

Comment: See de Boef, S., & Keele, L. (2008). [Taking Time Seriously](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~franzese/DeBoefKeele.2008.TakingTimeSeriously.pdf). *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1), 184–200 for a gentle introduction to time series models. Also: Welcome to CV!

Comment: I will definitely read the article, thank you so much